# What probability to select in calculating Bayesian power?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, statistical-power

I am comparing a Frequentist to a Bayesian test, running many simulations of the experiment.

I want to compare the power of both tests, *assuming the Null is true*.

For the frequentist test, I can fix an $\alpha$, say 5%, and find the proportion of times the p-value is > 5%, correctly failing to reject the Null.

For the Bayesian test, I get a distribution of probabilities in favor of the Null. Great. But how do I choose a cut off? Intuitively, if I treat Type I and Type II errors, I would choose 50% right? Is there another way to frame this? Do I put some sort of loss function on top of this in order to determine my "power"?

Any insight is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If you simulate from the prior, you simulate from both models with probabilities equal to the prior probabilities of the two models. Then you either use the posterior probability and compare it with a bound, or the Bayes Factor and compare it with one (1).

Comment: Right - "...compare it with a bound..." - my question is: what bound and how do you choose it? Sounds like if you choose BF > or < 1, its similar to setting a posterior bound of 0.5...?

Comment: Not really: the Bayes factor aims at an "objective" bound and removes the impact of the prior probabilities of null and alternative hypotheses. The posterior probability relates to both the prior probabilities and the consequences of being wrong, i.e., a loss function. For instance, when testing for ESP, if your prior probability that there is ESP is .0001, you would not conclude that there is ESP when the posterior probability is above .0001.